# micro service timeout and transaction

Tags: transactions, timeout, microservices

Given the micro service architecture, when a call to the service is timed out, the caller simply give up.  However, the request finally was fulfilled and new records inserted.
The problem is that the caller system determined the request failed because of the timeout.  What would be the best way to maintain this transaction?

Comment: read about CAP problem

Comment: you should provide more information about the interface provided by the micro service. There are request/response oriented microservices, message (queue) based microservices and there could also be event based microservices.

All of these expose different kinds of communication that have large impacts on the ability to detect and (if possible) subsequently handle the error.

Comment: It's HTTP RESTful service and all Synchronized service.  I think the issue is just edge case and implementing distributed transaction is costly.  So I just want to see if there are any mature pattern that I can follow instead of customize my own.  Unfortunately the caller is out of my control so I wonder if there are ways to easily roll back when the caller give up during  the case of timeout.  I guess there are not a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to guarantee consistency between the service consumer and the service provider as they are separated by the network. Both the request transmission and the response transmission can result in errors and in some edge cases the response message might even get lost on the wire without the service provider noticing what went wrong.

I think it might help you to look into the terms "nullipotent" and "idempotent". The first refers to operations that have no effects on the service provider (e.g. no change in stored data such as reading data), whereas the second speaks about operations that can be invoked any number of times without changing the outcome (e.g. calling delete one or ten times still means the data is gone, even if alter calls return the exception stating "data is already gone": the data is gone after the call).

Finally there are operation that are neither of the two, for example "add a new element to the list". I forgot the term for it, but basically these operations turn error handling into nightmares are you have little to no change of resuming operations after the error in a way that guarantees the same outcome, if there was one, many or no error during your request sequence.